# How to speedup iOS Xcode compilation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, codenameone

I have two projects based on LLVM Objective-C/C with 1M lines of code and 1.5M lines of code.

The 1.5M LoC project compiles faster for some unclear reason. It doesn't use precompiled headers and there is no explanation I could find.

I've added precompiled headers and included the biggest offenders, I've disabled dSYM generation, made the code compile ARM 7 only (not 7s) reduced the amount of optimizations to O3. Still the builds are much slower, the projects are pretty similar in structure but I can't see any major difference that would justify the slower build.

The faster building project was constructed with an older version of xcode but both are compiled with xcode 5.

Comment: any custom build phases? that could be rebuilding things unnecessarily..

Comment: I don't think so. Forgot to mention that neither project uses ARC.

Comment: Also check the "Enable modules" setting.

Comment: any "external" targets? i.e. Make builds? same potential problem... I wouldn't expect to spend a lot of time building if you're just changing code in 1 file and hitting build for example. (Unless those changes are in a .h file used lots of other places)

Comment: Enable modules is set to yes and missing from the old project, what does it do?

We don't have external targets, this is for a build server so its always a clean build executed via xcodebuild.

Comment: Enable modules is a special optimization of precompiled headers for system frameworks. See WWDC 2013 video [What's New in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/index.php?id=400) for more information. It has lots of ancillary benefits, too.

Comment: The big bulk of the code is C and a relatively small amount. Its enabled but since the old project has the exact same Objective-C code and is compiled under xcode 5 I doubt its the main reason.

Comment: By the way, do you know what is the average method length for both project?

Comment: The methods for the newer project are slightly longer even though the total LoC is smaller and the code is simpler. I think that one of the reasons for the slow compiles is the macros that are used relatively extensively (this is machine generated code). However, the code is really simple so its hard to determine that.

Comment: Off topic, but is it "MM lines of code" or just "M lines of code"? Are we talking millions, or...?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that. In the past one of our proof readers used to fix my phrasing to MM instead of M until I researched it a bit and it turns out the MM is very common in the financial sector but nowhere else so M should be used...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed that changing the c language dialect to C99 from GNU99 roughly doubles the compilation speed.

We also noticed that using macros extensively (define statements) especially nested macros are REALLY slow on xcode. Removing as much of those as possible also helped tremendously and our compilation is now 2-3 times faster.

**Update:** Since that we also discovered that includes within headers and in general over-use of include statements was also a contributor to performance issues. By reducing the number of includes we were able to further increase the compilation speed significantly well beyond the original project. I had incorrectly assumed that due to the usage of an SSD and caching having the typical C #ifdef guards against double include would be enough to make compilation fast but it seems LLVM is really slow with such includes for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into **Objective-C Modules**: a compiler optimization since xcode 5. This could really speed up your compile time, by using the `@import` in your code instead of `#import`.
By using this statement, the compiler only imports the used classes of the imported framework, instead of all the header files included in that framework.

More info:

http://stoneofarc.wordpress.com/2013/06/25/introduction-to-objective-c-modules/

Here's the WWDC 2013 session were it was introduced: 
Session 404: Advances in Objective-C

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/

Comment: Thanks, see the discussion in the comments section above. Most of the code is in C so this probably won't make a major difference. The objective-C code is almost identical between both projects so that wouldn't explain the difference.